# Tridion Advance Search error

Tags: search, search-engine

While using the SDL Tridion Advance Search Option I am getting the following error:

> Tridion search not working (`http:\\localhost:8983\tridion`) failed with the following response: The connection can not be authenticated. Unable to retrieve a search results" error.

Can anyone help me out to fix this error?

Answer (score 8):

1. First check if your search server is up and running by going to http://tridion-cm.tridion.com:8983/tridion. If it's not accessible, check whether the **Tridion Content Manager Search Host** service is running.
2. Then check with which user you are able to log in. Usually this is MTSUser. In the SDL Tridion Content Manager MMC snap in, go to **Search Settings** and check if for both the **Query Engine Settings** and the **Indexer Service Settings** the login credentials are properly entered.
3. If you need to make a change in configuration, restart all search related services.
4. Re-test your search in the Tridion CM GUI.

Answer (score 3):

In Addition to what Raimond has recommended, ensure that on your CMS server, there is a User Group named - **SDLSearchUsers** - and your MTS User (or the user with which your SDL Tridion Content Manager DCOM+ Application is running) is a part of this group.

These group settings although get set during the installation, but may get changed as per the IT policies or in case you have opted to change your MTS user.

The below screen shot may give you an idea:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had to perform an additional step on a server with existing Tridion installation which was cloned to another place.

- In %TRIDION_HOME%\solr-tomcat\conf\web.xml update `<role-name>` nodes, one in `<security-role>` and the other one in `<security-constraint>`, to match name of the new server (like SERVER_CM_NEW\SDLSearchUsers instead of SERVER_CM_OLD\SDLSearchUsers). Restart Tridion Content Manager Search Host service afterwards.